# rate-limiter-flexible + plan usage per user

Tags: node.js

I play with this package `rate-limiter-flexible` but I can't do what I want.

I explain , I would like each user have a `counter` and when this counter is reach user is blocked and `user` can reset this counter if he pay a `new package api` call.

At this moment I can `block` an user when he reach `maximal point` :

```
const opts = {
  storeClient: redisClient,
  points: 10, // 100 points
  //duration: 15*60, // Per 15 minutes
  duration: 0,
};

const rateLimiterRedis = new RateLimiterRedis(opts);

const rateLimiterMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const isIpLimited = req.ip;
  if (isIpLimited) {
    // Consume 1 point for each request
    rateLimiterRedis.consume(req.ip, 1)
      .then((rateLimiterRes) => {
        console.log(rateLimiterRes)
        // There was enough remaining points
            
      })
      .catch((rejRes) => {
        // All points consumed
        const secs = Math.round(rejRes.msBeforeNext / 1000) || 1;
        res.set('Retry-After', String(secs));
        res.status(429).send('Too Many Requests');
      });
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

app.use(rateLimiterMiddleware);
```

Maybe I can try to use .set method ... any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know two options:

1. Create a rate limiter with 1,000,000,000 points. Consume depending on usage plan: freemium consumes 10,000,000 points per request, silver plan consumes 1,000,000 per request, gold plan consumes 1,000 points per request, etc. Delete previously consumed points by IP, when a new plan bought.
2. Create separate rate limiter for each plan with different amount of points. Consume from appropriate rate limiter depending on user's plan.